# Send data from Arduino to Android

Tags: android, arduino

I'm trying to use an Android device to control an Arduino through Bluetooth. I able to control an [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) and a few component at the Arduino. But I don't know how to have Android receive data from the Arduino similar to how the BlueTerm application works.

How can I do this? I don't want to use the Amarino library, because I don't want to have to use an extra .jar.

Comment: show some code you have tried so far

Comment: What is BlueTerm? What is Amarino?

Comment: int val = 0;     // variable to store the read value
int ledPin1=7; //Indicator led
int ledPin2=8;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);      // sets the digital pin 7 as output
pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);      // sets the digital pin 8 as output
  
}

void loop(){
for(int i=ledpin1;i<=ledpin2;i++){
     val = digitalRead(i);
if ( val==HIGH ) {
           Serial.print(i);//Send to bluetooth HIGH pin
           digitalWrite(i,HIGH); 
           delay(1000);
           digitalWrite(i,LOW);
      }
} else {
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);  // turn LED OFF
    }
  }
}

Comment: @SalahAhmadAlJardali You shouldn't expect anyone to untangle that mess.  Edit your original post with code blocks to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a small library called [Amarino](http://www.amarino-toolkit.net/). I have used it in the past and it provides a VERY simple interface for communicating from Android to Arduino and visa versa. It has a great deal of tutorials and you can even read the creators thesis to get a full understanding of how everything works behind the scenes.